# Setting a default value for a referenced object id mongoose

Tags: mongoose, nodes

I have been trying to set a default value for a field in a mongo collection as a result of the following error with no success. I'm using mongoose.

```
ValidationError:  validation failed: client: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "" at path "client"
```

Have tried the following but failed:

```
client: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client', default: undefined }
```

also

```
client: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client', default: null },
```

The objective is for the client value to be optional. Client id is being referenced from client's collection.